# WPI - Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-platform-installer

I am at a total loss when it comes to WPI and the continous reinstallation of Visual Studio 2010 SP1.  I have even went as far as creating a virgin machine and installed VS2010 and then immediatly installed the tools from WPI.  After completion (which shows success) I reboot the machine and then load the WPI again to add on secondary tools.  At which point, the WPI triggers an installation of the SP1 -- 90 minutes later, the list shows up as successful, and other tools are listed for installation.

Every time you run WPI, it wants to go through the VS2010 setup over and over.  Is there any way to fix this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.